# Undefined Offset 1 and 2

Tags: php

I am having Undefined 1 and 2 on line 32 and 33. I don't even have an idea of what is going on and what the error means. How can i fix this please?

```
$splittedGSM = str_split($gsm);
    $correctGSM = TRUE;

    if(count($splittedGSM ) != 11) $correctGSM = FALSE;
    if($splittedGSM[0] != 0) $correctGSM = FALSE;
    if($splittedGSM[1] != 7 && $splittedGSM[1] != 8 && $splittedGSM[1] != 9) $correctGSM = FALSE; //Line 32
    if($splittedGSM[2] != 0 && $splittedGSM[2] != 1) $correctGSM = FALSE; //Line 33
    foreach ($splittedGSM as $realgsm) {
        if(!is_numeric($realgsm)){
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

Comment: which one is line 32 and 33 in this code ?

Comment: It is there in the code 
if($splittedGSM[1] != 7 && $splittedGSM[1] != 8 && $splittedGSM[1] != 9) $correctGSM = FALSE; //Line 32
    if($splittedGSM[2] != 0 && $splittedGSM[2] != 1) $correctGSM = FALSE; //Line 33

Comment: have to try with if(!isset($splittedGSM[1])){$splittedGSM[1] = null } condition ?

Comment: offset is not defined because it's not set you have to use isset function for it

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code. Offset is not defined because it's not set you have to check that if it's not set then offset will be null. You have to use isset() function for it.

```
    $splittedGSM = str_split($gsm);
    $correctGSM = TRUE;

   // check using isset function
    if(!isset($splittedGSM[1]))
    {
            $splittedGSM[1] = null;
    }
    if(!isset($splittedGSM[2]))
    {
            $splittedGSM[2] = null;
    }
    if(count($splittedGSM ) != 11) $correctGSM = FALSE;
    if($splittedGSM[0] != 0) $correctGSM = FALSE;
    if($splittedGSM[1] != 7 && $splittedGSM[1] != 8 && $splittedGSM[1] != 9) $correctGSM = FALSE; //Line 32
    if($splittedGSM[2] != 0 && $splittedGSM[2] != 1) $correctGSM = FALSE; //Line 33
    foreach ($splittedGSM as $realgsm) {
        if(!is_numeric($realgsm)){
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you try to access elements 1 and 2 of `$splittedGSM` without first checking that they exist.  You are probably calling `str_split` with an empty string as argument, in which case a one-element array containing the empty string will be returned. This explains why you don't get an error when accessing `$splittedGSM[0]`.
As you require a valid result to contain 11 elements, you can solve the problem by only accessing the array elements if the length test is satisfied, using `elseif` instead of `if`:

```
$splittedGSM = str_split($gsm);
$correctGSM = TRUE;

if(!is_array($splittedGSM) || count($splittedGSM ) != 11){
  $correctGSM = FALSE;
}elseif($splittedGSM[0] != 0){
  $correctGSM = FALSE;
}elseif($splittedGSM[1] != 7 && $splittedGSM[1] != 8 && $splittedGSM[1] != 9){
  $correctGSM = FALSE;
}elseif($splittedGSM[2] != 0 && $splittedGSM[2] != 1){
  $correctGSM = FALSE;
}
foreach ($splittedGSM as $realgsm) {
  if(!is_numeric($realgsm)){
     return FALSE;
  }
}
```